# @ControllerAdvice overrides exception @ResponseStatus

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I'm not sure why but the `@ControllerAdvice` is overriding the response code defined at `Exception` level using the `@ResponseStatus` annotation.

Exception:

> @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
> public class GreetException extends RuntimeException {}

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class GreetController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greet() {
        throw new GreetException();
    }
}
```

Controller Advice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionConfiguration {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    public void handleConflict() {}
}
```

When the greet method from the `GreetController` gets called the response is 409 - CONFLICT. Because i specifically provided a response code on exception level I expected that will be the returned code (400 - BAD_REQUEST).

Of-course this is an overly simplified example but we defined an controller advice with `RuntimeException` definition so we could assign an id to every exception that was not caught.

What is the correct way to achieve the expected behaviour?

Comment: in you controllerAdvice class you should use GreetException class as ExceptionHandler instead a RuntimeException class. **@ExceptionHandler(GreetException.class)
    public void handleConflict() {}**. Last class to be executed when an exception is thrown will be your controllerAdvice.

Comment: May be [this link should help](http://www.ekiras.com/2016/02/how-to-do-exception-handling-in-springboot-rest-application.html)

Comment: @duardito The exception handler for RuntimeException is to catch everything that was not caught. Because I declare a response status for the GreetException I don't expect to use the RuntimeE handler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem with annotating the exception with `@ResponseStatus` is, that this only triggers when the exception is not handled somewhere else.

See this quote from a [Spring article about exception handling in Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc):

> When an annotated exception is thrown from a controller method, and not handled elsewhere, it will automatically cause the appropriate HTTP response to be returned with the specified status-code.

The same article describes the approach to make it work despite having a `ControllerAdvice` with a general handler. See [Paragraph about ControllerAdvice](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#using-controlleradvice-classes).

What you basically would have to do is to rethrow the exception inside your general handler if it is annotated with `@ResponseStatus`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionConfiguration {

  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
  @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
  public void handleConflict(RuntimeException e) throws RuntimeException {
    // Check for annotation
    if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(e.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class) != null) {
      // Rethrow Exception
      throw e;
    }
    else {
      // Provide your general exception handling here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is clearly the correct answer. I skimmed through the article before posting here..I'll be more careful next time.

Comment: When handling a ResponseStatusException, I had to remove the if statement as it contains the ResponseStatus in a field, not annotation. After that it worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> Your ControllerAdvice does not know about GreetException, so it is
>   throwing "HttpStatus.CONFLICT" instead of "HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST"

Please find the below spring documentation for your ref:

https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Please change the ControllerAdvice code as below:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionConfiguration {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    public void handleRuntimeException() {}

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(GreetException.class)
    public void handleGreetException() {}

}
```